# Tensor product of A-module M with itself equals M

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Suppose that $A$ is a commutative ring and $M$ is an $A$-module such that $M \otimes_A M=M$. Is it true that $M=A$?

If not, does the answer change if $M$ is a ring and $A \subset M$?

Comment: To the first question: $0 \times_R 0 = 0$. Also, do you mean $A$ instead of $R$ ?

Comment: $A=R$ in your post?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb Q \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Q = \mathbb Q$ gives a negative answer to both questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sufficient condition which implies $M=A$:

> Let $A$ be a field and $M$ a nonzero $A$-algebra (not just an $A$-module). Assume the underlying isomorphism of $M\otimes_R M=M$ is the multiplication map $m\otimes m'\mapsto mm'$. Then $M=A$.

Under these assumptions, we have a composition of $A$-module isomorphisms:

$A\otimes_A M\longrightarrow M\longrightarrow M\otimes_A M$,

$a\otimes m\longmapsto am\longmapsto 1\otimes am=a1\otimes m$.

So this composition is induced by tensoring the structural map $A\rightarrow M$ with the identity $\mathrm{id}_M$.

Now we recall a fact:

> Every nonzero module over a field is faithfully flat.

This holds since modules over fields are always free.

Since $M\ne0$, the structural map $A\rightarrow M$ (which is a ring map) is injective.

So we may regard $A\subset M$ via this map (which satisfies your 2nd concern).

Now $M$ is faithfully flat over $A$. Thus, the structure map $A\rightarrow M$ becomes an isomorphism, i.e. $M=A$.

**Remark.**
The source of this special case is Bosch's book on Néron models.
On page 35: At the end of the proof of Proposition 2.2/2, we encounter a similar question to yours. The book uses dimension argument, but I actually didn't see why $A$ is a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space there. So I used faithful flatness to circumvent this issue.